# Rails Copy Button Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I have an object "device" that contains a good deal of attributes. When editing one of the devices, I want to to have a copy button that when pressed will create a new device and load its "edit page" with the old devices parameters filled into the text_field. But I am very confused on how to called action control methods with buttons and I am currently getting an error saying

"No route matches {:action=>"clone", :controller=>"device", :id=>"1"}"

If I could just get the call to the "clone" method to work then I think I would be in good shape. Any help would be greatly appreciated! My current code is as followed:

edit.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
<%= form_for(@device) do |f| %>

  <div class="span3 offset0">
    <%= f.label "Unit Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :unitName %>

   .
   .
   .

    <%= f.label "Router Terminal Server IP" %>
    <%= f.text_field :routerTerminalServerIp %>
  </div>

  <div class="span3 offset0">

   <%= f.label "N2x Server" %>
   <%= f.text_field :n2xServer %>

   .
   .
   .

   <%= f.label "Last Changed On" %>
   <%= f.text_field :updated_at %>

   <%= f.label "Update, Copy, or Delete Device" %>
   <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-medium btn-info" %>
   <%= link_to "Clone", :controller => "device", :action => "clone" %>
   <%= link_to "Delete", device_path, class: "btn btn-medium btn-danger" %>
 </div>

 <% end %>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :devices
  root 'static_pages#home'
  match 'devices/clone',  to: 'devices#clone', via: 'get'  
end
```

devices_controller.rb

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @device = Device.new
  end

  def clone
    oldDevice = Device.find(params[:id])
    @device = Device.new
    @device = @oldDevice.dup
    @device.save
    redirect_to edit_device_path(@device.id)
  end

  def create
    @device = Device.new(device_params)
    @device.lastChangedBy = request.remote_ip
    if @device.save
     redirect_to edit_device_path(@device.id)
    else
        render 'new'
 end
   end

  def show
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    @device.lastChangedBy = request.remote_ip
     if @device.update_attributes(device_params)
        redirect_to edit_device_path(@device)
     else
        render "edit"
end

def destroy
    Device.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to root_url
end
end

private

    def device_params
      params.require(:device).permit(:unitName, ...., :owner)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the route like this:

```
resources :devices do
  member do
    get :clone
  end
end
```

Then you can use the `clone_device_path(id)` helper.

Also, you should consider using post method for this action and use button instead of link.

Comment: How would I set up the button_to to use the clone_devise_path(id) helper?

Comment: Sth like `<%= button_to 'Clone', clone_devise_path(@devise.id) %>`.

Comment: I hate to keep bothering you about this, but I'm still having a problem getting the clone button to work. Right now, the clone button functions the exact same as the "edit" button. I tried deleting everything in the "clone" method and having it only "redirect_to root_url" but it only refreshed the edit page. It seems like it doesn't call the method properly.

Comment: Try adding sth like `raise "foo"` inside the method and check whether you got anything

Comment: I changed it from "button_to" to "link_to" and that got me inside the method!! Leaving it as button_to didn't throw an error, but using link_to threw a runtime error at the raise "foo" line. Without it, after hitting the clone button, "can't dup NilClass."

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have no end of obscure problems if you name your controller method 'clone', as that is already defined in ruby on Object: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-clone

It used to be overridden in ActiveRecord, but lately ActiveRecord uses #dup for this functionality. You can still use 'clone' in your route and in the link label, but use something else for the actual method in your controller; you might want to use an ' :as => 'my_clone' ' option in your routes, if you call your method 'my_clone" for instance.